# i have an error message in jQuery.readyException

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-3

i want update jquery to lately version

so i was replace 1.11.0 with 3.1.0

but it is not working

i have an error message 
'unexcepted exception in Lib/js/lib.jquery.js, 'safari' is not undefined'

this error is appeared in jquery.readyException

how can i fix it

```
    jQuery.readyException = function( error ) {
         window.setTimeout( function() {
             throw error; // this point have error.
         } );
    };
```

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: my code was worked when use 1.11.0 version....I do not know where I made mistakes

Comment: I would guess jquery 3.1.0 doesn't support your browser. Does it work with 2.2.x?

Comment: Can you reproduce error at plnkr http://plnkr.co or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: sorry i can't open and share it because it is my company's project and very huge code...

Comment: Not certain how issue can be resolved if cannot be reproduced?

Comment: i solved this problem with downgrade jquery version 3.0.0, readyExexception function was added at 3.1.0 .but i still dont know what is wrong in code